# Why does git use 'rm' for remote and '-d' for branch deletion?

Tags: git

I find it confusing to that in git, to remove a remote you use 'remote **rm**'...

```
git remote rm myremote
```

...while the syntax for deleting a branch requires the **-d** (or **-D**) switch:

```
git branch -d mybranch
```

Is there a logical reason for this inconsistency (which could perhaps assist me in remembering it correctly)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the syntax to create a branch is just `git branch mybranch`, not `git branch add mybranch`.

What if you had a branch called `rm`?

Comment: OK, that makes sense to me. It's like some commands consist of one word (`branch`) and others of two (`remote rm`).